# Not able to start Tomcat 7.0.79 in Windows

Tags: java, tomcat

I've installed Jdk9 in my Windows at the place

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
```

and I'm able to get the JAVA_HOME path in command prompt as its set as environment variable.

I've downloaded Apache Tomcat 7.0.79 version and trying to start it using command prompt, but it doesnt start.

Please check it

```
C:\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79\bin>startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:
\development\apache-tomcat-7.0.79\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

What is the exact issue here

Comment: Check $CATALINA_HOME/logs folder. You may find something in logs.

Comment: please show the full log trace

Comment: @JaydeepRajput, I didnt add catalina home in system variable. Do I need to add?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen, there is nothing in logs folder